# Is it possible to import swagger API into APIM from an authenticated source?

Tags: rest, powershell, azure, authentication, azure-api-management

We have swagger docs that require authentication to get at them.  I'm aware of how to import swagger docs from a url into APIM via REST API or PowerShell commandlet, however, I would need to be able to somehow pass in an authentication token so that I can get to the swagger docs that require authentication.  Is this possible with APIM REST API or PowerShell commandlets?

If it's not possible to authenticate through the APIM REST API, is it possible to simply pass in the swagger definition as a string?  I've only seen the possibility to import via file or url using the powershell commandlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to make APIM pass some credentials while fetching swagger, but if you get it youself (or via script) it's sure possible to just send it to APIM to import. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/apis#Apis_CreateOrUpdate.

PUT request with Content-Type: application/vnd.swagger.doc+json would imply that the body of request contains swagger document. So if you can fetch document before hand and send it in PUT request everything should work fine.

Comment: I am using azure management api and using swagger definition to upload json file but i am confused like those endpoints definition needs to be defined somewhere like if i talk about azure api demo calculator swagger.When i will call this :http://calcapi.cloudapp.net/api/add?a={a}&b={b}".Where this add method is defined?

Comment: Originally API is exposed by some backend, like this calcapi.cloudapp.net exposes /api/add operation to add numbers, or like twitter exposes /search api to search tweets.

Swagger file is used to describe an API, where it's hosted, what credentials are required to call it, which operations are supported e.t.c.

At import time APIM creates a representation of an API and starts proxying requests to it. So when you call XXX.azure-api.net/calc/add, APIM service will call calcapi.cloudapp.net/api/add and return its result to you.